# How to add new user and add new referense in Firebase from Web site(HTML,JS)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I found a solution on the Internet, but it is for the old version of Firebase, now it works every other time or does not work at all.
I have a simple Html website with content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="    viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.7/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="form.js"></script>
    <title>Login System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="formContainer" align="center">
       
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email"><br>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"><br>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="FIO"><br>
        <label>position</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="position" id="DOLZH"><br>
        <label>Place of work </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Place of work" id="Workplace"><br>
        <label>Tab number</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Tab number" id="TabNumber"><br>
        <button onclick="signUp()" id="signUp">Create User</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have JavaScript:

```
  //firebaseConfig has my correct data
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const auth =  firebase.auth();

  //signup function
  function signUp(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    const username=document.getElementById("email").value.split("@",1);
    var messageRef=firebase.database().ref(username[0])
    const fiouser=document.getElementById("FIO").value;
    const work=document.getElementById("Workplace").value;
    const tabnum=document.getElementById("TabNumber").value;
    const dolzhnost=document.getElementById("DOLZH").value;
    var errorcount=0;
    var promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value,password.value);
    promise.catch(e=>alert(e.message));
    
    if (errorcount==0){
    try{
                var newMessageRef=messageRef;
                newMessageRef.set({
                "*Должность":dolzhnost,
                "*Место работы":work,
                "*Табельный номер":tabnum,
                "*ФИО":fiouser,
                })
            }
            catch(e){
                alert(e.message);
            }
    }
    if (errorcount==0){
        alert("Пользователь успешно зарегистрирован!")
        location.reload();
    }   
  }
```

Does anyone know a way to add a user to Firebase Auth and add a new Reference to Firebase Realtime Database for new versions?:)
P.S. I known that my JS script is bad:)

Comment: The Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) has sample for both version 8 and before and version 9 and later, so you can compare and translate the code by comparing those. You can also use compat mode of v9 as explained in the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).